# Transformations of the x-y plane

Tags: linear-transformations

If we have some transformation $S(x,y) = (x+1,y)$, and we want to find the equation of $y=x^2 + 2x + 2$ after the $x-y$ plane is transformed, we would substitute $(x-1)$ in place of $x$ in the equation, but we know that if we have the graph of $f(x)$ then we find $f(x-1)$ the graph is moved forward. Could someone provide some intuition on what the transformation $S$ actually does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transformation moves every point of the x-y plane one unit to the right.

Comment: Alright, why is this different to the transformation of a graph? $f(x+1)$ moves a graph to left, but here it moves to the right.

Comment: The transformation says how the y-axes moves to the right ,  the f(x-1) says that the graph moves, relativ to the given y-axes